# Hide div when responsive menu activated?

Tags: html, css

I have a Joomla website with the afterburner theme.

When viewed on mobile the navigation menu toggle appears as a button on top right (standard mobile way of displaying a nav menu).

The problem I'm having is there's too much content above the nav menu so when the nav menu opens you can't see it without scrolling down. I know I could just remove this entirely on mobile but I'd rather not.

Here is the CSS that deals with the menu

```css
.clearfix {
    *zoom: 1;
}
.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {
    display: table;
    content: "";
    line-height: 0;
}
.clearfix:after {
    clear: both;
}

ul.level3 {

}

.hide-text {
    font: 0/0 a;
    color: transparent;
    text-shadow: none;
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 0;
}
.input-block-level {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 30px;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.rok-left {
    float: left;
}
.rok-right {
    float: right;
}
.rok-dropdown-group,
.rok-dropdown {
    position: relative;
}
.rok-dropdown-open .rok-dropdown {
    display: block;
}
.rok-popover-group,
.rok-popover {
    position: relative;
}
.rok-popover-open .rok-popover {
    display: block;
}
.gf-menu {
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px #ffffff;
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px #ffffff;
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px #ffffff;
}
.gf-menu-toggle {
    padding: 7px 10px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    background-color: #f0f0f0;
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff, #dadada);
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#ffffff), to(#dadada));
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff, #dadada);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff, #dadada);
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #ffffff, #dadada);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ffffffff', endColorstr='#ffd9d9d9', GradientType=0);
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    top: 10px;
    left: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.gf-menu-toggle.active {
    background-color: #dcdcdc;
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #cdcdcd, #F3F3F3);
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#cdcdcd), to(#F3F3F3));
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #cdcdcd, #F3F3F3);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #cdcdcd, #F3F3F3);
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #cdcdcd, #F3F3F3);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ffcccccc', endColorstr='#fff3f3f3', GradientType=0);
}
.gf-menu-toggle .icon-bar {
    background-color: #32373D;
    border-radius: 1px 1px 1px 1px;
    display: block;
    height: 2px;
    width: 18px;
}
.gf-menu-toggle .icon-bar + .icon-bar {
    margin-top: 3px;
}
@media (max-width: 767px) {
    .layout-mode-responsive .gf-menu-device-wrapper {
        margin-bottom: 15px !important;
    }
    .layout-mode-responsive .gf-menu-device-container {
        background: #741c1b;
        border-radius: 5px;
        padding: 5px;
    }
    .layout-mode-responsive .gf-menu-device-container select {
        margin-bottom: 0;
        width: 100%;
    }
    .layout-mode-responsive .gf-menu {
        background-clip: content-box;
        -webkit-background-clip: content-box;
        background: #741c1b;
        border: none !important;
        -webkit-box-shadow: none;
        -moz-box-shadow: none;
        box-shadow: none;
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0;
    }
    .layout-mode-responsive .gf-menu ul {
        padding-left: 20px;
    }
    .layout-mode-responsive .gf-menu li {
        margin-right: 0 !important;
    }
    .layout-mode-responsive .gf-menu li.active.last {
        border: 0 !important;
        -webkit-box-shadow: none !important;
        -moz-box-shadow: none !important;
        box-shadow: none !important;
    }
    .layout-mode-responsive .gf-menu li.active.last > .item {
        border-radius: 4px;
        background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
    }
    .layout-mode-responsive .gf-menu li:hover > .item {
        color: !important;
    }
    .layout-mode-responsive .gf-menu li .item {
        padding: 0 10px !important;
        border: none !important;
        color: #FFFFFF;
        line-height: 30px;
    }
    .layout-mode-responsive .gf-menu li .item.subtext em {
        display: none;
    }
    .layout-mode-responsive .gf-menu li .item:after {
        content: '' !important;
        border-right: 0 !important;
    }
    .layout-mode-responsive .gf-menu .dropdown {
        width: 100% !important;
        border: 0 !important;
        padding-top: 0 !important;
        padding-bottom: 0 !important;
        background: transparent !important;
        -webkit-box-shadow: none !important;
        -moz-box-shadow: none !important;
        box-shadow: none !important;
        position: relative;
        left: inherit;
        top: inherit;
        opacity: 1;
        *zoom: 1;
    }
    .layout-mode-responsive .gf-menu .dropdown:before,
    .layout-mode-responsive .gf-menu .dropdown:after {
        display: table;
        content: "";
        line-height: 0;
    }
    .layout-mode-responsive .gf-menu .dropdown:after {
        clear: both;
    }
    .layout-mode-responsive .gf-menu .dropdown .flyout {
        display: block;
    }
    .layout-mode-responsive .gf-menu .dropdown .column {
        width: 100% !important;
    }
    .layout-mode-responsive .gf-menu .dropdown .grouped ol {
        -webkit-box-shadow: none !important;
        -moz-box-shadow: none !important;
        box-shadow: none !important;
        border: 0 !important;
        margin: 0 !important;
        padding: 0 !important;
    }
    .layout-mode-responsive .gf-menu .dropdown .modules {
        display: none;
    }
    .layout-mode-responsive .gf-menu.l1 > li {
        float: none;
    }
    .layout-mode-responsive .gf-menu.l1 > li.active {
        margin-left: 0px;
        background: transparent;
        -webkit-box-shadow: none;
        -moz-box-shadow: none;
        box-shadow: none;
        border: 0;
    }
    .layout-mode-responsive .gf-menu.l1 > li > .item {
        font-size: 15px;
        line-height: 40px;
        border-right: none !important;
    }
 .layout-mode-responsive .gf-menu ul.level3 {
  display:none; 
 }
 
 .layout-mode-responsive .award-winning {
 display:none;
 }
}
```

What I want to happen is when the following is run

```
.gf-menu-toggle.active {
```

It should then also have a 'display:none' for certain divs (i.e div="awards"). I'm not sure how this can be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

To apply styles to "certain divs" (`div#awards`) within the specific selector (`.gf-menu-toggle.active`), do this:

```css
.gf-menu-toggle.active div#awards { display: none; }
```

This will apply the `display: none` style to whatever element you want it to within the `.gf-menu-toggle.active` element.

Comment: That's how I hoped it would work but unfortunately has no effect. Is it because, as CreMedian said, the div is outwith the .active class?

Comment: Ahh I see. In that case, if they aren't contained or connected in any CSS-selectable relation, you'll probably need to use javascript like @CreMEdian posted

Answer (score 0):

Unless the "certain divs" that you want to hide are contained inside the one with the `.active` class you are targeting with CSS, then you will not be able to hide them using CSS.

You have 2 options:

1) See if another class gets added to the body or some element higher in the hierarchy so you can target that to get at your "certain divs"

2) Use some jQuery like this:

```
 $('ul').click(function(){
   var certainDivs = $('div#awards, #other-div, .certain-div');
   if ($('.gf-menu-toggle').hasClass('active')){
     $(certainDivs).hide();
   }
   else{
     $(certainDivs).show()
   }
 });
```

That jQuery should be bound to an event (like when the `<ul>` is clicked or something) so the function fires and does its thing.

Good luck!